# Matching two sets when you cannot do within-set comparisons

Tags: algorithms

Suppose you have two lists, `A` and `B`, each with length n.  The elements of A cannot be compared with other elements of `A`--there is no order relation among them--and likewise for `B`.  However, elements of `A` can be compared with elements of `B`.  So for instance, suppose we have a function `compareTo(a,b)` where `a` is an element of `A` and `b` is an element of `B`.  If `a` is less than `b` it returns -1, if they're equivalent it returns 0, and if `a` is greater it returns 1.

Further suppose that a perfect matching exists between the elements of `A` and `B`, in the sense that for every element of `A` there is precisely one element of `B` such that `compareTo(a,b)` evaluates to 0.  And vice versa (for each `b` there is precisely one `a` such that they're equivalent).

How do we write an efficient algorithm to find the perfect matching?

---

My attempts: Well, there's the naive algorithm which takes an element of `A` and finds its corresponding element of `B`, repeating until all matchings have been found.  This runs in O(n^2) so we want to beat this.

It sounds kind of like Gale-Shapley but an input to that algorithm is a preference list.  In this setting we have ties, where preference lists don't.  And even generating something like a preference list would take n^2 time.  Since it is fundamental to Gale-Shapley that members of one set propose to their highest preferences of the other, this doesn't seem applicable to the given problem.

We could try to use an element of `A` to partition the set `B` and try to divide-and-conquer.  But you would only have divided `B` and wouldn't know which elements of `A` to give to the recursive call.  You could then try to use `B` to partition `A`.  To describe this more, let's give a specific example.  Suppose `A = [a1,a2,a3,a4]` and `B = [b4,b1,b3,b2]` and suppose that `ai < bj` if `i < j`, and likewise for `=` and `>`.  We could arbitrarily select `a1` and then use it to partition `B` into the elements that come out greater in the comparison, `[b4,b3,b2]` and the elements that come out smaller `[]`.  Since along the we way we found that `a1` matched `b1` we make that assignment and eliminate them from the rest of the algorithm.  Now that we know `a1` was quivalent to `b1` we can use `b1` to partition `A` into `[]` and `[a2,a3,a4]`.  We recursively call the algorithm on the smaller sets `[], []` which satisfies the conditions: they have the same length and have perfect matching.  And recursively call the algorithm on the larger sets `[a2,a3,a4], [b4,b3,b2]` which also have the same length and have a perfect matching.

I think this algorithm is correct, but in the worst case it doesn't beat the worst-case runtime of the naive algorithm.  So I don't think I'm on the right track here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the so-called "nuts and bolts" problem, and your pivoting approach can be shown (under uniform choices of pivots) to give a randomized algorithm with expected query complexity $O(n \log n)$, using the analysis of Quicksort as a template.

Fast deterministic algorithms are less obvious. The first true breakthrough paper I know of for this is that of [Alon et. al.](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/PAPERS/nuts_bolts.pdf), which shows one simple algorithm with query complexity  $O(n^{1.5} \sqrt{\log n})$ (basically by combining the quicksort approach you describe with a moderately expensive pivot-finding procedure), and another much more involved one with complexity $O(n\,\textrm{polylog}\,n)$ (also based on quicksort, but the identification of the pivot goes through some more hardcore expander machinery).

Subsequently, [Komlós et. al.](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0895480196304982?journalCode=sjdmec) found an asymptotically optimal algorithm with $O(n \log n)$ deterministic query complexity using a different approach based on sorting nets.